How can I tell what's included in a Steam special edition?
Given a Steam product listing, is there a way to tell what is included in a "special edition" of a game?
For example, I'm looking at RobotCop: Rogue City on Steam. I see two options to buy, the regular game and a "Alex Murphy Edition" for US$10 more (non-sale price.)

How can I figure out what's included in the special edition -- in this case the "Alex Murphy Edition" -- so that I can decide whether it's worth the extra $?

Normally for special editions (eg: digital delux, etc, there is a button underneath to view what is included in it.)

However, for this specific game if you look lower on the steam page, there is a section called "Special Offer" which has a graphic showing what is in the Alex Murphy Edition.

